Heteroscedastic variance prediction constant where it should not be
I am trying to make predictions about the heterscedastic noise in my dataset. I have an FPN already set up, treating the variance as an additional class. My dataset is the aerial semantic segmentation drone dataset. Here is the model:
class FPN(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, encoder_name="resnet34", encoder_weights="imagenet", in_channels=1, activation=None, decoder_dropout=0.3):
    super(FPN, self).__init__()
    self.base_model = smp.FPN(
        encoder_name=encoder_name,
        encoder_weights=encoder_weights,
        in_channels=in_channels,
        classes=2,
        activation=activation,
        decoder_dropout=decoder_dropout
    )

def forward(self, x):
    mean, var = torch.split(self.base_model(x), 1, dim=1)
    var = torch.nn.functional.softplus(var)
    return torch.cat((mean, var), dim=1)

The loss function is pytorch's standard NLL-Gaussian Loss:
class CustomGaussianLoss(base.Loss):
def __init__(self):
    super(CustomGaussianLoss, self).__init__()
    self.gaussian_nll_loss = nn.GaussianNLLLoss()

def forward(self, input, target):
    mean, var = torch.split(input, 1, dim=1)
    
    loss = self.gaussian_nll_loss(mean, target, var)
    return loss 

However, just after the first epoch, the variance is always predicted as constant 0.69 for every pixel. The pixel values are scaled between 0 and 1. Interestingly, 0.69 is roughly the variance of the dataset accross pixels.
All this makes no sense to me, given this dataset. Even if the variance were roughly constant, which it isn't, the magintude is all wrong. Ideas?
